# How can I export each line of a csv file with powershell

Tags: shell, email, powershell, csv, exchange-server

I am currently moving away from a script we have that queries the Message Queues wmi object within Exchange Server (2007-2013) to run solely within Powershell.

Below is my code, albeit not the best (I am still new to this) which I have tested on 2007 and 2013 versions of Exchange (Amending where appropriate) And this works perfectly, it extracts each row from the initial exported csv and sets the content with what the results I am looking for:

One CSV file per row

However I have made a rookie mistake! not everyone of our client servers will house 4 Message queues on their exchange, this is going to vary from anywhere between 2 and a variable I can't be sure of so if this was to run on an Exchange server with 3 message queues, well you guessed it, my results would skew since my dir clause is configured for only 4 files, sigh.

Is there any ps experts out there who can pull me up on my code on this and point me in the right direction on successfully exporting rows without running into issues like this?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010

$output= "C:\Support\ExchangeQueue.csv"
$output1= "C:\Support\ExchangeQueue1.csv"
$output2= "C:\Support\ExchangeQueue2.csv"
$output3= "C:\Support\ExchangeQueue3.csv"

$Hubs= Get-ExchangeServer | Where {$_.ServerRole -like "*Hub*"}
    $Hubs | foreach{

Get-Queue | Select-Object -Property Identity, MessageCount, NextHopDomain | 
    Export-Csv -path $output -NoTypeInformation

Get-Queue | Select-Object -Property Identity, MessageCount, NextHopDomain |
    Export-Csv -path $output1 -NoTypeInformation

Get-Queue | Select-Object -Property Identity, MessageCount, NextHopDomain |
    Export-Csv -path $output2 -NoTypeInformation

Get-Queue | Select-Object -Property Identity, MessageCount, NextHopDomain |
    Export-Csv -path $output3 -NoTypeInformation
}

    (Get-Content $output) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ''}|Out-File $output
    (Get-Content $output1) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ''}|Out-File $output1
    (Get-Content $output2) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ''}|Out-File $output2
    (Get-Content $output3) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ''}|Out-File $output3

dir $output | %{
    $content = gc $_.FullName
    $outputfile = @($content | select -First 1 )
    $outputfile += $content[1..($content.count -4)]
    $outputfile | Set-Content $_.FullName -Force

    (Get-Content $output | 
        Select-Object -Skip 1) | #Delete header
        Set-Content $output
}

dir $output1 | %{
    $content1 = gc $_.FullName
    $outputfile1 = @($content | select -First 1 )
    $outputfile1 += $content[2..($content.count -3)]
    $outputfile1 | Set-Content $_.FullName -Force

     (Get-Content $output1 | 
        Select-Object -Skip 1) | #Delete header
        Set-Content $output1
}

dir $output2 | %{
    $content2 = gc $_.FullName
    $outputfile2 = @($content | select -First 1 )
    $outputfile2 += $content[3..($content.count -2)]
    $outputfile2 | Set-Content $_.FullName -Force

     (Get-Content $output2 | 
        Select-Object -Skip 1) | #Delete header
        Set-Content $output2
}

dir $output3 | %{
    $content3 = gc $_.FullName
    $outputfile3 = @($content | select -First 1 )
    $outputfile3 += $content[4..($content.count -1)]
    $outputfile3 | Set-Content $_.FullName -Force

     (Get-Content $output3 | 
        Select-Object -Skip 1) | #Delete header
        Set-Content $output3 
}
```

Comment: An example of your CSV file would be helpful.

Comment: I'm confused by what the `$Hubs | foreach{ [...] }` loop is doing.  The loop doesn't use the pipeline object at all anywhere.

Comment: @DaveSexton Here are a few links to my CSV files, I feel it would be easier for you to physically see what I am looking for. One contains the results I need to manipulate and the other is my final output (note no quotations or header(s)).

http://www.filedropper.com/exchangequeues

http://www.filedropper.com/exchangequeuerow1

Comment: @BaconBits Hi Bacon Bits, You can pipe a variable to the foreach loop as if you run the following:



Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

    $output= "C:\Support\ExchangeQueue.csv"

$Hubs= Get-ExchangeServer | Where {$_.ServerRole -like "*Hub*"}
    $Hubs | foreach{
 
Get-Queue | Select-Object -Property Identity, MessageCount, NextHopDomain | 
    Export-Csv -path $output -NoTypeInformation
}

You will see it runs the string on all hubs detected.

Comment: @KieranGroome I don't think that's right.  You're not running `Get-Queue -Server $_.Name | [...]`.  Just running `Get-Queue` without identifying the queue or server will [return all queues for the server you're running the cmdlet on](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124904\(v=exchg.141\).aspx).  All you've done is used `$Hubs` to repeat the same code over and over.  You could replace it with `1..4` and have the same results.  Unless `Get-Queue` magically reads pipelines when it hasn't been told to, you're not looking at anything but the current server's queues.

Comment: @BaconBits I don't need to run -Server $_.Name as I only want the queues on the specific server it is ran on, and I want it to return all the queues rather than identifying/specifying queues, which is why I am looking for it to then Import-CSV and export each row to a separate CSV, so in one sense Import (INSERT REMOVAL STRING HERE for csv rows 1,3,4 leaving row 2), select-object -skip 1 (Removing the headers) Export-CSV $newcsv and then I have a new csv with one row? I hope I am making sense to you. The reason I need this is because it will be ran on more than one Exchange server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a whole lot of logic here that I think is not necessary.  Here's how I would write what I think you're trying to do, assuming you're running it on each Exchange server:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010;

$OutputFilePattern = 'C:\Support\ExchangeQueue{0}.csv';

$ServerRole = (Get-ExchangeServer).ServerRole;
if ($ServerRole -like '*HubTransport*' ) {
    $AllQueues = Get-Queue | Select-Object -Property Identity, MessageCount, NextHopDomain;

    $OutputFileNum = 0;
    foreach ($Queue in $AllQueues) {
        $OutputFileNum++;
        $OutputFile = $OutputFilePattern -f $OutputFileNum;

        #Buffer and Set-Content used here instead of Export-Csv due to quoting
        $Buffer = @();
        $Buffer += 'Identity,MessageCount,NextHopDomain';
        $Buffer += '{0},{1},{2}' -f $Queue.Identity, $Queue.MessageCount, $Queue.NextHopDomain;
        Set-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $Buffer -Force;
    }
}
```

You may need to use the `ToString()` method on several of these objects to get them to work correctly.  Namely, `(Get-ExchangeServer).ServerRole.ToString()`, and then later `$Queue.Identity.ToString(), $Queue.MessageCount.ToString(), $Queue.NextHopDomain.ToString()`.  I'm not in a position to run these cmdlets anymore, so I'm relying on the MSDN doc for their data types and parameters.

Comment: This is great, albeit you did pretty much re write my code here so 100% credit to you sir, you have helped me learn how to successfully export rows of content to individual csv files which is just what I needed! I have added some changes for Exch 2013 clients as HubTransport does not exist when running Get-ExchangeServer clause. Thank you ever so much for this & fortunately I did not even have to integrate the `ToString()` extensions. Does adding the `{0}` onto the end of my OutputFile essentially become a variable for naming the file extensions? I would like to understand key string further

Comment: @KieranGroome Basically. The `{0}` is the reference for the format operator (`-f`), which is pretty powerful.  `Get-Help about_Operators` talks about it briefly, and points you to the [String.Format method](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=166450) and [composite formatting](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=166451).  There's [many](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) good [articles](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pstips/archive/2014/10/18/powershell-s-format-operator.aspx) about the format operator out there.